# not getting fullscreen background or font

Tags: java, graphics

I don't know what is wrong. I am supposed to go to full screen, set background, and add text. I get full screen and the background color, but there is no text on screen. I am following a tutorial and I had to deviate and add super. Paint (g) and   getContentPane (). setBackground (Color. PINK); to get the background color. Other than that, I think I followed the tutorial completely. I also  edit the main method and my one class beneath.

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Screen {
    
    private GraphicsDevice vc;
    
        public Screen() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();  
        }
    
        public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);
        
            if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
            
                try {
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                }catch (Exception ex) {}
            }
           }
        
        
        public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
            return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            
        }
        
        
        public void restoreScreen() {
            Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            if(w != null) {
                w.dispose();
            }
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }       
}
```

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class HybridMain extends JFrame   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,16,DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    HybridMain hb = new HybridMain();
    hb.run(dm);
    
    }
    
    public void run(DisplayMode dm) {
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        setFont(new Font("Areal", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        
        Screen s = new Screen();
        
        
        try {
            
            s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch(Exception ex) {}
        } finally {
            s.restoreScreen();
        }
    }
    
    
    public void Paint (Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g); 
        g.drawString("this is", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive.  Add `@Override` to your `Paint` method and see what happens.  Having said that, you should avoid painting directly to top level containers like `JFrame` and use a `JPanel` instead.  Also, setting the `font` this way won't affect what is painted

Comment: You should start with [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) to get a better understanding of how the paint system works ... and how you should work with it and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) wouldn't hurt either

Comment: I changed to  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);, so now I atleast get color right.